# Show database details for item selected in spinner

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite, simplecursoradapter, android-cursorloader

I am using a SimpleCursorAdapter to populate a Spinner with the name column from a database.

Adapter:

```
spinnerAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(
        this,
        android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,
        null,
        new String[] {SupplierEntry.COLUMN_SUPPLIER_NAME},
        new int[] {android.R.id.text1},
        0);
spinnerAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
mSuppliersSpinner.setAdapter(spinnerAdapter);

getLoaderManager().initLoader(SUPPLIERS_LOADER, null, this);
```

Cursor Loader:

```
@Override
    public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int i, Bundle bundle) {
        // Define a projection that specifies the columns from the table we care about.
        String[] projection = {
                SupplierEntry._ID,
                SupplierEntry.COLUMN_SUPPLIER_NAME};

        // This loader will execute the ContentProvider's query method on a background thread
        return new CursorLoader(this,        // Parent activity context
                SupplierEntry.CONTENT_URI,   // Provider content URI to query
                projection,                  // Columns to include in the resulting Cursor
                null,                        // No selection clause
                null,                        // No selection arguments
                null);                       // Default sort order
    }
```

How could I, upon selecting an item in the spinner (the name column), show all the other details in some textviews ?

Answer (score 1):

First, set a listener to the spinner so you get a callback when an item is selected.

```
mSuppliersSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
```

I supply 'this' as listener because my Fragment / Activity implements the interface, but you can write one between the brackets as well.
You can implement this method:

```
@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)
{
    //Start another cursorloader to get the details
}
```

Based on the id, or the position, you know which entry was selected. At this point you can start another CursorLoader (with a selection so you only get the details of this particular entry). When you get a callback in onLoadFinished, you can show the details in the TextViews.